# How to change the language for the Wear OS emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, wear-os

I checked all the settings in the watch emulator, but I can't figure out how to set the language. It seems like the language is set by the connected phone. My emulator is not connected to a phone though. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a really handy app installed by default on the emulator called "Custom Locale". It allows you to change the locale of the device, which can be used to change the language.

Click the ADD NEW button to enter a local on the format xx_YY. Apply the new locale and exit the app to verify that the language has been updated. I changed it to Swedish and you can see in the screenshots below that the title is updated from "Recents" to "Senaste".

Pleae note that not all languages are supported by the system.

[image: current locale app]

[image: current locale app UI]

[image: app drawer in swedish]

Comment: Thanks @TofferJ! I am still getting some parts in English, mainly in the settings menu (even after a reboot), but the language in the apps changed correctly.

Comment: Yes, I've also noticed that. It seems like not all parts of the system and default apps support other languages. But it should allow you to test anything you build yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To change language of WearOS emulator. Scroll the app list and find `Custom Locale` app.

**Select `en-us` for English language**.

[image]

If you want to use your custom locale or language Click on `Add new locale code`. Enter preferred locale code Click `Add and Select`. Enter `hi` for `Hindi` language.

[image]

Custom lacale below

[image]